# Understanding docker - how do containers contain all required dependencies?

Tags: docker

I am trying to understand Docker.

My understanding is that effectively a container is like an application AFTER the sinatller has been run, but containing only the installed files in their final destinations.  Is this right?

If yes, what about all the dependencies?  How did the program that created the container know all the dependencies that the program will need?

Sorry the questions are noobish but I'm trying to properly grasp Docker.

Answer (score 2):

The program that created the container is the `docker` daemon. It doesn't know anything about the application dependencies. It does know about file systems. You generally start with a "base image", a ready-for-installation root file system like `ubuntu` or `centos`. Then when you add new software, that gets added to a new "image" on top of the old one.

So if you installed software into the container, everything you installed in a persistent way (e.g. on disk) stays on that file system. In fact, since this file system is a "copy on write" file system, it knows exactly what the new files are, so it can efficiently package just the parts you added into an "image" layer. That new "image" will never change. The new image, plus the base image, can start a runnable container (which now has a new layer added to capture any changes *it* makes).

A container is more than an independent file system though. It is also an isolated process tree and a network interface.

Comment: OK so I'm now puzzled.  How can it be possible to run a Docker image on a different base image? Would it not often be the case that the Docker image depends on something in the original base that it was built from?

Comment: Yes, each image depends on the layer it was built on. You cannot change base images without also rebuilding all the layers above it.

Comment: so if I needed node.js in my image, would I install it in the directory where the Dockerfile exists? I don't have to specify instructions in the Dockerfile to install node.js at the time the image is built?

Comment: you can pick an image that already has nodejs like the official node ones. For example add `FROM node:latest` at the top of your `Dockerfile` to use the latest node.

Answer (score 0):

For the container to have all required dependencies, you will need to define them in the dockerfile while building the new image.
If you choose the right image, you can skip installing most of the required dependencies.
Docker daemon won't know what is required or what is not.
It will create a container on 'docker run' and you can use 'docker container logs' or 'docker container inspect' to know more about the container.